# Does kotlin string has the programmer like Objc static NSString kUrl = @"users/%@/profile";

Tags: android, objective-c, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin, i encountered a problem, i want to define some constant url strings. And most of the constant strings contain some variables inside the string like: "/users/24/profile". In Objc i can declare the url by

```
static NSString kUrl = @"/users/%@/profile";
```

and i can give the %@ value when i using it like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:kUrl,24]
```

But in kotlin, i don't know if there is something like that. What i know in kotlin is :

```
const val kUrl = "/users/{0}/profile"
```

and do

```
kUrl.replace("{0}",24)
```

when i using it. if there are many parameters i will define many placeholder{0},{1} ...., it could be complex.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation to archive the same as in Obj-C:

```
val userId = 24
const val kUrl = "/users/$userId/profile"
const val kUrl = "/profile/$firstname/$surname"
```

**But** it's not a safe way to construct url. Say, your `firstname` happen to be "na/?/me" - that would break url structure. To avoid this issue strings must be **encoded** to be safe to placed into url

To archive so consider `URLEncoder` helper class

val valueEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(value, "utf-8");

then it can be safely plugged into the url string:

```
const val kUrl = "/users/$valueEncoded/"
```

or, path parameters encoding can be done in place

```
const val kUrl = "/users/${URLEncoder.encode(value, "utf-8")}/"
```

#### Kotlin way

If you noticed that you need to convert parameters often it's possible to create an extension function in the limited scope where it's need, for instance:

```
fun String.toUrlSafe() = URLEncoder.encode(value, "utf-8")

// Use
val url = "/path/${param1.toUrlSafe()}/${param2.toUrlSafe()}/something"
```

Comment: Thanks @rux. However this is not i want. It introduced a val to reach this effect. when i want define a lot of urls, i must define a lot of different types of vals.

Comment: @tynewstar could you please provide an example of the ultimate goal?